# Test espresso with Travis

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to test integration tests with Travis-CI. I have the yml:

```
language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

sudo: false

android:
  components:
  - platform-tools
  - tools
  - build-tools-25.0.2
  - android-25
  - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

  #Extras
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-android-m2repository

before_script:    
  - android list targets
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: 
  - ./gradlew test
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
script: "./travis-build.sh"
```

This should work, but I am always getting:

Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the target ids.

I have no idea how to fix this problem...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You downloaded `android-25` but passing `android-22` as target I'd for emulator

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old VM (used with `sudo: false`) [only include platforms up to android-21](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/blob/a68419ebe0ce92876a70534cd145ddd931d0feee/ci_environment/android-sdk/attributes/default.rb), please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475535/1009132)

```
language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

sudo: false

android:
  components:
  - platform-tools
  - tools
  - build-tools-25.0.2
  - android-22 # Android platform used by your alternative emulator
  - android-25
  - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

  #Extras
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - extra-google-m2repository  # Removed duplicated component

before_script:    
  - android list targets
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: 
  - ./gradlew test
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
script: "./travis-build.sh"
```